# Gpu processing R (How to use Gpu processing to run a function on subsets of a dataset)

Tags: r, gpu

I have a large dataset (around 5 million observations). The observations record the total revenue from a specific event by different type of subevents denoted by "type". A small replication of the data is below:

```
Event_ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
Type=c("A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D")
Revenue1=c(24,9,51,7,22,15,86,66,0,57,44,93,34,37)
Revenue2=c(16,93,96,44,67,73,12,65,81,22,39,94,41,30)
z = data.frame(Event_ID,Type,Revenue1,Revenue2)
```

**I would like to use GPU cores to run a function that I wrote (I have never attempted GPU processing, so am at a complete loss how to begin). The actual function takes a really long time to run. I am showing a very simple version of the function below:**

```
Total_Revenue=function(data){
  full_list=list()
  event_list=unique(data[,'Event_ID'])
  for (event in event_list){
    new_data=list()
    event_data = data[which(data$Event_ID==event),]
    for (i in 1:nrow(event_data)){
      event_data[i,'Total_Rev'] = event_data[i,'Revenue1']+event_data[i,'Revenue2'] 
      new_data=rbind(new_data,event_data[i,])
    }
  full_list=rbind(full_list,new_data)
  }
  return(full_list)
}

Total = Total_Revenue(data=z)
print(Total)
```

This simplified version function proceeds as follows:

a) Break up the dataset into subsets such that each subset only takes 1 unique event.

b)For each observation, loop through all the observations and compute Revenue1+Revenue2.

c)Store the subsets and at the end return the new dataset.

**Since I have no prior experience, I was looking at some of the R packages. I found the gpuR package and installed it.** However, I am having difficulty in understanding how to implement this. Also the issue is that my coding background is very weak. I have self taught myself some things over the past year.

Any help/leads will be highly appreciated. I am open to using any alternate packages as well. Please let me know if I missed anything.

P.S. I also took a snapshot of my system using the following command:

```
str(gpuInfo())
```

I am attaching the output for your reference:

[image]

P.P.S. Please note that my actual function is a little complicated and long and it takes a long time to run which is why I want to implement gpu processing here.

Answer (score 0):

GPU programming is no silver bullet. It works well only for certain problems. That's why the `gpuR` package provides GPU base vectors and matrices allowing for linear algebra operations to be done using the GPU. This won't help you if your problem is no a linear algebra problem. However, note that many problems can be *formulated* as in such a way.

We cannot tell if your problem falls into this category, since you have (probably) over-simplfied your code:

```
> print(Total)
   Event_ID Type Revenue1 Revenue2 Total_Rev
1         1    A       24       16        40
2         1    B        9       93       102
3         1    C       51       96       147
4         1    D        7       44        51
5         1    E       22       67        89
6         2    A       15       73        88
7         2    B       86       12        98
8         2    C       66       65       131
9         2    D        0       81        81
10        2    E       57       22        79
11        3    A       44       39        83
12        3    B       93       94       187
13        3    C       34       41        75
14        3    D       37       30        67
```

Since `Total_Rev` is just the sum of `Revenue1` and `Revenue2`, you could have done this more easily:

```
> z$Total_Rev <- z$Revenue1 + z$Revenue2
> z
   Event_ID Type Revenue1 Revenue2 Total_Rev
1         1    A       24       16        40
2         1    B        9       93       102
3         1    C       51       96       147
4         1    D        7       44        51
5         1    E       22       67        89
6         2    A       15       73        88
7         2    B       86       12        98
8         2    C       66       65       131
9         2    D        0       81        81
10        2    E       57       22        79
11        3    A       44       39        83
12        3    B       93       94       187
13        3    C       34       41        75
14        3    D       37       30        67
```

This is a simple form of vectorization, which helps you getting rid of (some) `for` loops. And since you outer `for` loop looks at different `Event_ID`, it might also make sense to look into grouping and aggregation techniques. These can be done with base R, the `data.table` package, with `tidyverse`/`dplyr` and possibly other tools. I am using the latter approach, since I fond its syntax the most newbie friendly. However, `data.table` might be the right tool for you if you have large data sets. So here a very simple aggregation that computes the average per `Event_ID`:

```
Event_ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
Type=c("A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D")
Revenue1=c(24,9,51,7,22,15,86,66,0,57,44,93,34,37)
Revenue2=c(16,93,96,44,67,73,12,65,81,22,39,94,41,30)
z = data.frame(Event_ID,Type,Revenue1,Revenue2)

library(dplyr)
z %>%
  mutate(Total_Rev = Revenue1 + Revenue2) %>%
  group_by(Event_ID) %>%
  summarise(average = mean(Total_Rev))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Event_ID average
#>      <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1        1    85.8
#> 2        2    95.4
#> 3        3   103
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I admit that I do not understand GPU processing well (or you could say at all). Unfortunately, my problem is not a simple linear algebra operation. Thank you anyways. Is there a R package or some other way that I can break up a big operation and run it on individual GPU cores? Unfortunately I could not find any example other than matrix multiplications (which is not what I would like to do). You are correct in that I might have over-simplified my problem. My apologies. I wanted to understand how to use GPU for running an operation on subsets of a big dataset.

Comment: @Prometheus Please not that  the main efficiency gain from using the GPU comes when all cores act in lock-step. That is they execute exactly the same instructions just with different data. I am not sure your use case has that form. From what you write it sounds more like an aggregation problem. That can be efficiently solved using `data.table`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53366310/8416610.

Comment: Yes you are right. That is why I made sure that the "operation" for each event is run one at a time. I believe this is called embarrassingly parallel process. The "operation" is not a simple aggregation as I have shown here though. The "operation" was simplified for illustrative purposes. Thanks a lot.